# Python: How to extract a List thats inside an array, which is inside a list?

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, extract

Been trying to figure this out everyday for a week...

I am receiving data, then using json.loads and variable-ing it.
Here is the print output that I cant seem to further variable-ize without error codes:

[548, {'a': ['**2364.66000**', 16, '16.94656538'], 'b': ['2364.65000', **8**, '8.45377850'], 'c': ['2364.66000', '0.35264111'], 'v': ['494.53876892', '**54702.28957251**'], 'p': ['2363.99238', '2359.02527'], 't': [404, 31739], 'l': ['2355.99000', '2258.59000'], 'h': ['2375.91000', '2453.03000'], 'o': ['2369.82000', '2338.83000']}, 'ticker', 'somerandontextcharacters']

Trying to assign one or more of these boldly-specific numbers to variables, you know, so I can have my way with them.

**P.S. x = [548,{thewholething-etc...]**

P.S.S. the data is received from a websocket connection response using .recv command, then json.loads'ed. Some of the printed outputs are in {etc,etc,} but some are in the form of [etc,{etc,etc,}]

Comment: I suggest u should add the output example,It hard to see what's u really want

Comment: x = json.loads(response)
print(x) # displays the above

Comment: Only seeing error codes when trying to extract & assign variables from x

Comment: That isn't an error, just a list of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy actually:

```
test = [{'a' : [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]}] # this is just an example

var1 = test[0]['a'][1] # should be 2
var2 = test[0]['b'][2] # should be 6

print(var1)
print(var2)
```

Output:

```
2
6
```

Comment: with x = json.loads(pub.recv())
 print(x[1]['a'][1])

Comment: Let me post a few lines, one reply at a time, 1 sec

Comment: x = json.loads(pub.recv())    print(x)

Comment: Heres the Response:

Comment: {'connectionID': 17234373327, 'event': 'systemStatus', 'status': 'online', 'version': '1.8.6'}

Comment: {'channelID': 548, 'channelName': 'ticker', 'event': 'subscriptionStatus', 'pair': 'ETH/USD', 'status': 'subscribed', 'subscription': {'name': 'ticker'}}

Comment: [548, {'a': ['2379.87000', 8, '8.30000000'], 'b': ['2379.20000', 7, '7.61166173'], 'c': ['2379.20000', '0.10575000'], 'v': ['1488.42961203', '55035.29415629'], 'p': ['2367.56985', '2359.44388'], 't': [1083, 31756], 'l': ['2354.00000', '2258.59000'], 'h': ['2380.83000', '2453.03000'], 'o': ['2369.82000', '2346.98000']}, 'ticker', 'ETH/USD']
{'event': 'heartbeat'}

Comment: Above are three different "ticks" of a the websocket response.... I get the error when trying to print(x[1]['a'][1]). Is it because the responses have different forms?

Comment: :'(   < me pulling my hair out for the past week

Comment: keyerror when trying print(x[1]['a'][1]) instead of print(x). Print statement is in a "While True: Try:" if that matters. Is there a way to filter all responses for "beginning with [548.." ?

Comment: if x[0] == 548?

Comment: OMG YES it successfully did it on the third message, BUT threw key errors for every response that didnt start with [

Comment: It worked thank you so much. Now if only I had a way to filter responses that start in { or in [

Comment: You sir deserve a reward. Im going to your profile.

Comment: You can filter by checking the type of each: `if type(x) == list`.

Comment: For anyone who has read this far down, the problem has been solved. The problem itself was that websockets feed LISTs and DICTs, and the program wouldnt run at all when trying to print contents from a list without IF type(x) == list. Thank you for immediately responding, and thank you for sticking with me the whole way to the solution @Have_a_nice_day. All of your responses helped solve this!